# Keep program running after close

Tags: python, tweepy

I am working on a marketing program for twitter and I want to be able to schedule a tweet. I have the script working, but once I put it into the interface and the program is finished, i want to be able to schedule a tweet for say, an hour away and be able to completely power off my computer and still have the tweet post when scheduled. as I have it now if i leave the script running it will post when I say, but if i close it it will not. here is the code after tweepy authorization

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)
tweet = raw_input("what do you want to tweet in 1 hour?")
print "you have scheduled your tweet for 1 hour"
sched = True
while sched is True:
    time.sleep(3600)
    api.update_status(tweet)
    sched = False
if sys.exit:
    continue
```

thanks ahead of time. as you can see i tried to continue the program after sys.exit but that doesnt work

Comment: "an hour away and be able to completely power off my computer" that is ambitouos, indeed. Makes this more like a sys-admin question than a programming question.

Comment: I'm not clear on whether you expect your computer to turn itself back on and run this program or to run programs while powered off. Either way, I'd say you're in for a disappointment.

Comment: who ever gave -1 for all, don't be so uptight. its obvious that the person asking the question is a noob. In some sense all he wants is to do a scheduled tweet using python tweepy. Some times nudging people in right direction helps.

Answer (score -1):

How abt using nohup or cron jobs ?

Comment: could you possibly leave an example?

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/nohup-execute-commands-after-you-exit-from-a-shell-prompt.html

Answer (score -1):

In the way you ask for, this is impossible. How can your program run when your computer is completely powered off?

If your Twitter account has a credit card on file, you can use [Scheduled Tweets](https://business.twitter.com/en/help/campaign-editing-and-optimization/scheduled-tweets.html) to send tweets ahead of time, and have Twitter publish them at a predefined moment. I'm not sure there's an API for this.

Answer (score -1):

Continue:

> The continue statement, also borrowed from C, continues with the next iteration of the loop

So it does not Continue an already shut down instance.

Link:[Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html)
Link Schedule: [Schedule Github](https://github.com/dbader/schedule)

Since you asked for an example of Cron like Scheduling System why not Schedule:
But you would still have to have a running pc

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("test")

schedule.every(x).minutes.do(job)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: if i have to keep the computer on no matter what, then since I am putting it in an interface that stays open obviously until i close it, would i even have to use the schedule module? the script works perfect as is as long as i keep it up so since the interface would stay open as long as i want i don't think this is an issue anymore, although please let me know if thats not a safe assumption. thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can use python-daemon, But can used for linux platofrm only.:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
from daemon import runner
api = tweepy.API(auth)
class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.stdin_path = '/dev/null'
        self.stdout_path = '/dev/tty'
        self.stderr_path = '/dev/tty'
        self.pidfile_path =  '/tmp/foo.pid'
        self.pidfile_timeout = 5
    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(3600)
            api.update_status(tweet)


app = App()
daemon_runner = runner.DaemonRunner(app)
daemon_runner.do_action()
```

Here do_action is internally call run function.

Then just start it with command "./filename.py start", and stop it with "./filename.py stop".
But after poweroff machine daemon is stop. so you need to start manually after restart machine.